# SolrCloud 5.0 browse result perspective configuration

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine

**I got the result perspective from SolrCloud 5.0 with collection configured with example-DIH like this** :

[image: my solr result perspective]

**However, the supposed result perspective should be like this:**

[image: supposed solr result perspective]

**How can I configure the XML to change the perspective?**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself.
The configuration file in `*./server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/conf/*` can make the result perspective as rich as the second screenshot.
The configuration file can be used when creating collection. For example:

```
bin/solr create_collection \
-c techproducts \
-d server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/conf/ \
-shards 5 \
-replicationFactor 2
```